# Where should i store the photos that users upload?

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a mobile application and my server is in java. I use mysql for my data. Many requests from the devices will ask for photos. From what i see, storing images in mysql is very bad practice, so i will go with storing some path or url in my sql.
My question is, where should i store the images that users upload?

Comment: Use [imgur's public API](https://api.imgur.com/)? Or are these private photos?

Comment: What is the reason for that question? You can store the pictures in a directory as usual.

Comment: If you just want to “store” pictures to be able to show them on the web, then file system would be the answer. If you are going to need additional stuff like access control (pictures not visible to just “everyone”, but depending on f.e. the logged-in user), then that broadens the scope of your question by a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Server is fast enough to deliver the Images, just put it on your Server with an unique URL.

Comment: Although an answer, it's pretty vague. Where in the server? How to generate a unique URL? What if the server isn't fast enough? Should you cache the images (if so; how)? What checks on the images should you do to ensure security?